# How to output XML from BeautifulSoup without extraneous newlines?

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, elementtree

I'm using Python and BeautifulSoup to parse and access elements from an XML document. I modify the values of a couple of the elements and then write the XML back into the file. The trouble is that the updated XML file contains newlines at the start and end of each XML element's text values, resulting in a file that looks like this:

```
<annotation>
 <folder>
  Definitiva
 </folder>
 <filename>
  armas_229.jpg
 </filename>
 <path>
  /tmp/tmpygedczp5/handgun/images/armas_229.jpg
 </path>
 <size>
  <width>
   1800
  </width>
  <height>
   1426
  </height>
  <depth>
   3
  </depth>
 </size>
 <segmented>
  0
 </segmented>
 <object>
  <name>
   handgun
  </name>
  <pose>
   Unspecified
  </pose>
  <truncated>
   0
  </truncated>
  <difficult>
   0
  </difficult>
  <bndbox>
   <xmin>
    1001
   </xmin>
   <ymin>
    549
   </ymin>
   <xmax>
    1453
   </xmax>
   <ymax>
    1147
   </ymax>
  </bndbox>
 </object>
</annotation>
```

Instead I'd rather have the output file look like this:

```
<annotation>
 <folder>Definitiva</folder>
 <filename>armas_229.jpg</filename>
 <path>/tmp/tmpygedczp5/handgun/images/armas_229.jpg</path>
 <size>
  <width>1800</width>
  <height>1426</height>
  <depth>3</depth>
 </size>
 <segmented>0</segmented>
 <object>
  <name>handgun</name>
  <pose>Unspecified</pose>
  <truncated>0</truncated>
  <difficult>0</difficult>
  <bndbox>
   <xmin>1001</xmin>
   <ymin>549</ymin>
   <xmax>1453</xmax>
   <ymax>1147</ymax>
  </bndbox>
 </object>
</annotation>
```

I open the file and get the "soup" like so:

```py
    with open(pascal_xml_file_path) as pascal_file:
        pascal_contents = pascal_file.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pascal_contents, "xml")
```

After I've completed modifying a couple of the document's values I rewrite the document back into the file using `BeautifulSoup.prettify` like so:

```py
    with open(pascal_xml_file_path, "w") as pascal_file:
        pascal_file.write(soup.prettify())
```

My assumption is that the `BeautifulSoup.prettify` is adding these superfluous/gratuitous newlines by default, and there doesn't appear to be a good way to modify this behavior. Have I missed something in the BeautifulSoup documentation, or am I truly unable to modify this behavior and need to use another approach for outputting the XML to file? Maybe I'm just better off rewriting this using `xml.etree.ElementTree` instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to be straight-forward to get the indentation I want if I instead use `xml.etree.ElementTree` instead of BeautifulSoup. For example, below is some code that reads an XML file, cleans off any newlines/whitespace from text elements, and then writes the tree as an XML file.

```py
import argparse
from xml.etree import ElementTree


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def reformat(
        input_xml: str,
        output_xml: str,
):
    tree = ElementTree.parse(input_xml)

    # remove extraneous newlines and whitespace from text elements
    for element in tree.getiterator():
        if element.text:
            element.text = element.text.strip()

    # write the updated XML into the annotations output directory
    tree.write(output_xml)


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":

    # parse the command line arguments
    args_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    args_parser.add_argument(
        "--in",
        required=True,
        type=str,
        help="file path of original XML",
    )
    args_parser.add_argument(
        "--out",
        required=True,
        type=str,
        help="file path of reformatted XML",
    )
    args = vars(args_parser.parse_args())

    reformat(
        args["in"],
        args["out"],
    )
```

Answer (score 2):

> My assumption is that the BeautifulSoup.prettify is adding these
>   superfluous/gratuitous newlines by default, and there doesn't appear
>   to be a good way to modify this behavior.

**YES**

It is doing so in two methods of the `bs4.Tag` class `decode` and `decode_contents`.

**Ref:** [Source file  on github](https://github.com/waylan/beautifulsoup/blob/480367ce8c8a4d1ada3012a95f0b5c2cce4cf497/bs4/element.py)

If you just need a temporary fix, you can monkey patch these two methods

Here is my implementation

```
from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString, BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import AttributeValueWithCharsetSubstitution, EntitySubstitution


def decode(
    self, indent_level=None,
    eventual_encoding="utf-8", formatter="minimal"
):
    if not callable(formatter):
        formatter = self._formatter_for_name(formatter)

    attrs = []
    if self.attrs:
        for key, val in sorted(self.attrs.items()):
            if val is None:
                decoded = key
            else:
                if isinstance(val, list) or isinstance(val, tuple):
                    val = ' '.join(val)
                elif not isinstance(val, str):
                    val = str(val)
                elif (
                    isinstance(val, AttributeValueWithCharsetSubstitution)
                    and eventual_encoding is not None
                ):
                    val = val.encode(eventual_encoding)

                text = self.format_string(val, formatter)
                decoded = (
                    str(key) + '='
                    + EntitySubstitution.quoted_attribute_value(text))
            attrs.append(decoded)
    close = ''
    closeTag = ''
    prefix = ''
    if self.prefix:
        prefix = self.prefix + ":"

    if self.is_empty_element:
        close = '/'
    else:
        closeTag = '</%s%s>' % (prefix, self.name)

    pretty_print = self._should_pretty_print(indent_level)
    space = ''
    indent_space = ''
    if indent_level is not None:
        indent_space = (' ' * (indent_level - 1))
    if pretty_print:
        space = indent_space
        indent_contents = indent_level + 1
    else:
        indent_contents = None
    contents = self.decode_contents(
        indent_contents, eventual_encoding, formatter)

    if self.hidden:
        # This is the 'document root' object.
        s = contents
    else:
        s = []
        attribute_string = ''
        if attrs:
            attribute_string = ' ' + ' '.join(attrs)
        if indent_level is not None:
            # Even if this particular tag is not pretty-printed,
            # we should indent up to the start of the tag.
            s.append(indent_space)
        s.append('<%s%s%s%s>' % (
                prefix, self.name, attribute_string, close))
        has_tag_child = False
        if pretty_print:
            for item in self.children:
                if isinstance(item, Tag):
                    has_tag_child = True
                    break
            if has_tag_child:
                s.append("\n")
        s.append(contents)
        if not has_tag_child:
            s[-1] = s[-1].strip()
        if pretty_print and contents and contents[-1] != "\n":
            s.append("")
        if pretty_print and closeTag:
            if has_tag_child:
                s.append(space)
        s.append(closeTag)
        if indent_level is not None and closeTag and self.next_sibling:
            # Even if this particular tag is not pretty-printed,
            # we're now done with the tag, and we should add a
            # newline if appropriate.
            s.append("\n")
        s = ''.join(s)
    return s


def decode_contents(
    self,
    indent_level=None,
    eventual_encoding="utf-8",
    formatter="minimal"
):
    # First off, turn a string formatter into a function. This
    # will stop the lookup from happening over and over again.
    if not callable(formatter):
        formatter = self._formatter_for_name(formatter)

    pretty_print = (indent_level is not None)
    s = []
    for c in self:
        text = None
        if isinstance(c, NavigableString):
            text = c.output_ready(formatter)
        elif isinstance(c, Tag):
            s.append(
                c.decode(indent_level, eventual_encoding, formatter)
            )
        if text and indent_level and not self.name == 'pre':
            text = text.strip()
        if text:
            if pretty_print and not self.name == 'pre':
                s.append(" " * (indent_level - 1))
            s.append(text)
            if pretty_print and not self.name == 'pre':
                s.append("")
    return ''.join(s)


Tag.decode = decode
Tag.decode_contents= decode_contents
```

After this, when I did `print(soup.prettify)`, the output was

```
<annotation>
 <folder>Definitiva</folder>
 <filename>armas_229.jpg</filename>
 <path>/tmp/tmpygedczp5/handgun/images/armas_229.jpg</path>
 <size>
  <width>1800</width>
  <height>1426</height>
  <depth>3</depth>
 </size>
 <segmented>0</segmented>
 <object>
  <name>handgun</name>
  <pose>Unspecified</pose>
  <truncated>0</truncated>
  <difficult>0</difficult>
  <bndbox>
   <xmin>1001</xmin>
   <ymin>549</ymin>
   <xmax>1453</xmax>
   <ymax>1147</ymax>
  </bndbox>
 </object>
</annotation>
```

I made a lot of assumptions while doing this. Just wanted to show that it is possible.

Comment: Very nice work, thanks @Bitto Bennichan. I may rewrite my code using ElementTree as I'm hoping to not go as "off the reservation" as this and I don't think BeautifulSoup really buys me much that ElementTree doesn't offer (I used BS since it was used in a tutorial I was following for this task). Nice hack though, kudos!

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info) with Python's third-party module, `lxml` (which you possibly already have with `BeautifulSoup` integration). Specifically, call the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform) to copy XML as is and then run the `normalize-space()` template on all text nodes.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl, a special .xml file or embedded string)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- IDENTITY TRANSFORM -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
      <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
      </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- RUN normalize-space() ON ALL TEXT NODES -->
    <xsl:template match="text()">
        <xsl:copy-of select="normalize-space()"/>
    </xsl:template>            
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD FROM STRING OR PARSE FROM FILE
str_xml = '''...'''    
str_xsl = '''...'''

doc = et.fromstring(str_xml)
style = et.fromstring(str_xsl)

# INITIALIZE TRANSFORMER AND RUN 
transformer = et.XSLT(style)
result = transformer(doc)

# PRINT TO SCREEN
print(result)

# SAVE TO DISK
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
     f.write(result)
```

[Rextester demo](https://rextester.com/GRXNJ28906)

Comment: Thank you, @Parfait, this is helpful. I was hoping for something that just works out of the box instead of taking an approach like this, as this seems like almost as much work as rewriting my code to use ElementTree rather than BeautifulSoup. That assumes that the output from ElementTree will be formatted reasonably concisely unlike the default BeautifulSoup output, I guess there's only one way to find out (i.e. stop being lazy and do the rewrite using ElementTree). In any event, thanks again for your help.

Comment: Hmmm...saving a separate .xsl alongside .xml (or embed either as string as demo shows) is too much work? Without any loops or rewriting tree in Python? But understood. I don't know your full process just came to answer titled question. And I only use `lxml` for all my XML needs (even HTML) being a fully compliant XPath 1.0 and XSLT 1.0 library. Good luck! Maybe this can help future readers.

Comment: It turned out to be trivial to rewrite my code using ElementTree and the XML formatting looks as expected/desired when I use `ElementTree.write(file_path)`. This seems to be the easiest/simplest, for me anyway...

Comment: Great to hear! Glad it worked out. Feel free to answer own question. Hopefully it does not involve loops.

Comment: After a little more testing it turns out I was mistaken and it's not quite as simple as this. Before I rewrite the XML I need to update all elements with text values using strip() to remove extraneous whitespace and newlines. Nevertheless xml.etree.ElementTree seems to be easier to use for this and so I've started using that instead of BeautifulSoup for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

#### I wrote a code to do a prettification without any extra library.

**Prettification logic**

```
# Recursive function (do not call this method)
def _get_prettified(tag, curr_indent, indent):
    out =  ''
    for x in tag.find_all(recursive=False):
        if len(x.find_all()) == 0:
            content = x.string.strip(' \n')
        else:
            content = '\n' + _get_prettified(x, curr_indent + ' ' * indent, indent) + curr_indent
    
        attrs = ' '.join([f'{k}="{v}"' for k,v in x.attrs.items()])
        out += curr_indent + ('<%s %s>' % (x.name, attrs) if len(attrs) > 0 else '<%s>' % x.name) + content + '</%s>\n' % x.name
    
    return out 
    
# Call this method
def get_prettified(tag, indent):
    return _get_prettified(tag, '', indent);
```

**Your input**

```
source = """<annotation>
 <folder>
  Definitiva
 </folder>
 <filename>
  armas_229.jpg
 </filename>
 <path>
  /tmp/tmpygedczp5/handgun/images/armas_229.jpg
 </path>
 <size>
  <width>
   1800
  </width>
  <height>
   1426
  </height>
  <depth>
   3
  </depth>
 </size>
 <segmented>
  0
 </segmented>
 <object>
  <name>
   handgun
  </name>
  <pose>
   Unspecified
  </pose>
  <truncated>
   0
  </truncated>
  <difficult>
   0
  </difficult>
  <bndbox>
   <xmin>
    1001
   </xmin>
   <ymin>
    549
   </ymin>
   <xmax>
    1453
   </xmax>
   <ymax>
    1147
   </ymax>
  </bndbox>
 </object>
</annotation>"""
```

**Output**

```
bs = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
output = get_prettified(bs, indent=2)
print(output)

# Prints following
<annotation>
  <folder>Definitiva</folder>
  <filename>armas_229.jpg</filename>
  <path>/tmp/tmpygedczp5/handgun/images/armas_229.jpg</path>
  <size>
    <width>1800</width>
    <height>1426</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
  </size>
  <segmented>0</segmented>
  <object>
    <name>handgun</name>
    <pose>Unspecified</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
      <xmin>1001</xmin>
      <ymin>549</ymin>
      <xmax>1453</xmax>
      <ymax>1147</ymax>
    </bndbox>
  </object>
</annotation>
```

Run your code here: https://replit.com/@bikcrum/BeautifulSoup-Prettifier

Comment: I tried your code its working fine for html parser `bs = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')` but coverting all tags to lowercase.  when I used `bs = BeautifulSoup(source, 'xml')` it is giving correct case tags but creating  gap between lines.